# How to have a top-level SVN working dir, when contents don't mirror repo

Tags: svn

Bad title, let me provide an example:

### Repository

```
repo
|
|-- project1
|   |
|   |-- trunk
|   |-- tags
|   |-- branches
|
|-- project2
|   |
|   |-- trunk
|   |-- tags
|   |-- branches
|
|-- project3
|   |
|   |-- trunk
|   |-- tags
|   |-- branches
|
```

### Working copy

```
c:\work\my-wc
|
|-- project1   ( <== repo/project1/trunk)
|-- project2   ( <== repo/project2/trunk)
|-- project3   ( <== repo/project3/trunk)
```

I the top-level WC to act as a SVN WC so I can update it, have IDE tools let me drag files between projects, etc. But how is that possible, if at all? So far I manually checkout each project/trunk into a folder and obviously the parent directory is nothing to do with SVN at all.

The aim is to stop people checking out the entire branches/tags structure, which could be massive.

Comment: Are these projects projekt1, project2 related to each other? Means if you work on project1 you need to work on project2 as well ? If yes than the structure is wrong.

Comment: more like distinct library projects

Answer (score 0):

As you say people need all three projects in their working copy it is ideal you follow the below tree structure

```
repo
|
|-- trunk
|   |
|   |-- project1
|   |-- project2
|   |-- project3
|
|-- tags
|   |
|   |-- project1
|   |-- project2
|   |-- project3
|
|-- branches
|   |
|   |-- project1
|   |-- project2
|   |-- project3
|
```

check out [Planning Your Repository Organization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout)

As a workaround for your current situation you can think of having a svn:externals as a solution. But you might have problems in maintaining it on the long run.

These svn:externals link might help

http://amadiere.com/blog/2009/06/multiple-subversion-projects-in-one-visual-studio-solution-using-svnexternals/

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

http://blog.feryn.eu/2009/03/dealing-with-svn-externals/

Comment: The redbook presents your approach but doesn't prefer it (I've read that before). It's all a bit of a conundrum... I'll read up on externals though.

Comment: if you use externals, what happens when you have feature-branches?

Comment: re-organizing the branch is the best option for you. As said in my answer it is going to create a lot of maintenance. That is if you go with the externals approach you need to set the externals for every branch. However if you prefer the externals approach take the hook script path and see if you can set the externals automatically after the copy. Be advised, I don't really know what kind of adversities the hook script would create.